# jQuery events remain with document after off

Tags: javascript, jquery, bho

I'm creating a BHO and inserting scripts into facebook pages..my question is the following. Sometimes when I insert a script into a page(let's say) and bind some events to an event holder i.e.

```
 $('#contentArea').on('click','#myId',Dosomething);
```

they work fine.

After this, I remove the scripts from this page, and then add them back again(pls don't ask why, it's because *facebook* doesn't always generate a new document for a new page, rather it changes a portion of the document), and this time the events run multiple times(depends on how many times do I remove and then add them, so for 1 remove and 1 add they run twice, for 2 remove and 2 adds they run 3 times etc.) despite the facet that the first line of the script is

```
 $('#contentArea').off();
```

What am I missing here, cause I know the handlers do not get removed from the document, or the node...maybe it's an event bubbling problem?
BTW, I'm working in `internet explorer 9`.

Comment: question was clear. well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should at least do

```
 $('#contentArea').off("click");
```

or  the event listener may not be removed , maybe even

```
$('#contentArea').on('click','#myId');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the point is to remove a delegated handler that calls a function, you should probably, well, remove the function bound to that event and element?

```
$('#contentArea').off('click','#myId',Dosomething);
```

Comment: tried it, doenst work..pls see my comments to Stefan for more info :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) requires atleast one argument.

> **events** One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces,
>   or just namespaces, such as "click", "keydown.myPlugin", or
>   ".myPlugin".

Try to unbind all `click` events this way; `$('#contentArea').off('click');`

You might also be able to use [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to unbind all events.

> In the simplest case, with no arguments, .unbind() removes all
>   handlers attached to the elements.

Comment: Yeah...that was a serious mistake on my part..however...correcting the problem did not help..I tried $('#contentArea').off('click'), and even $('#contentArea').off('click','#myId',Dosomething), and no results...I tried adding them as first lines in the script, also after document complete with no results.. maybe I should try with namespaces?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that facebook does not generate a new document for let's say when you naviga from your friend's friends list to his info page and back again(it generates the content through some other means) and this is when the problems start to occur...however if I press f5 to refresh the page, a new document is generated and the events work fine again..this is why I believe that when navigating from friendslist to info page and back again the document object remains the same, and because my script get run 2 times, events get registered two times, and thats why they run 2 times

Comment: How are you reloading your scripts and do you really need to?

Comment: yes I really need to, because I am creating a BHO for Internet Explorer, and facebook removes my script when navigating, but doesn't necessarily generate a new document, so I need to reinsert them

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is why do you not check the element first to see if it has a handler? How could one accomplish such a task. Easy, we leave a trace on the element that lets us know if we have installed the handler or not. The element is a dom after all so we can just add an object member to it, or we can add an attribute

```
$(this).attr('myBHOInstalled','true');
```

then

```
if( $(this).attr('myBHOInstalled') !== 'true' ) {
    installMyBHO($(this));
```

`}`